# Jetty Websocket Scaling

Tags: node.js, websocket, java-websocket

what is the maximum number of websockets any one has opened using jetty websocket server. I recently tried to load test the same and was able to open 200k concurrent connections on a 8 core linux VM as server and 16 clients with 4 core each. Each client was able to make 12500 concurrent connections post which they started to get socket timeout exceptions. Also I had tweaked the number of open files as well as tcp connections settings of both client and server as follows.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=16777216
sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=16777216
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_rmem="4096 87380 16777216"
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_wmem="4096 16384 16777216"
sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=8192
sudo sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=16384
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=8192
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="1024 65535"
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=cubic
```

On the contrary one 2 core machine running node was able to scale upto 90k connections. 
 My questions are as follows

1. Can we increase the throughput of jetty VM any more
2. What is the reason of node.js higher performance over jetty.